# avoid adding duplicate object in dictionary and array of dictionaries ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i am newbie to iOS and making a cart screen having a table view each cell with two buttons one of them to add quantity and other to choose variant in the particular cell, i want to make an array of the no. of objects  chosen in the table view of last updated quantity and if  two different variants are chosen there should be two objects with their selected variants and their individual quantities too in array

```
-(void)addQuantityMethod:(id) sender
{
   ItemSelectTableViewCell *clickedCell = (ItemSelectTableViewCell *)         [[sender superview] superview];
   quantity = [clickedCell.qtyDisplayLbl.text intValue];
   NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.subMenuTblView  indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
   if (clickedButtonPath)
   {
      clickedCell.qtyDisplayLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++quantity];
   }

   [self.selectedDict setObject:clickedCell.itemNameLbl.text forKey:@"pName"];
   [self.selectedDict setObject:clickedCell.itemPriceLbl.text forKey:@"unitPrice"];
   [self.selectedDict setObject:clickedCell.lblSelectVariant.text forKey:@"variant"];
   [self.selectedDict setObject:clickedCell.qtyDisplayLbl.text forKey:@"qty"];
```

if anyone could help me out then please its being appears very much complicated for me to deal with as i am newbie.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You also appear to be using the tableview cell as a data store... :-/

Comment: yes it is a cart screen  having tableviewcell in table view,, using dictionary to save data of one cell and i have to make array of the dictionary based on selection of cells  ....means the customer will increase the quantities and choose the variant according to his choice. i have to update the variant key in dictionary and if choses two variants of same product then two objects of dictioanry should be there in array

Comment: That's not how it's done.  You use a `datasource` with tableviews and you then simply need to set a `selected` boolean in each object in the datasource array when an item is selected.  You should be using custom objects in the array, not a dictionary.

Comment: better if u could help me with the code

Comment: I'm sure it would be, but there are plenty of examples out there.  You don't have an issue with duplicate entries as you won't be adding anything to the array during the selection process.

Comment: i did this by seeing seeing examples somewhere     [self.arrayForCart addObject:self.selectedDict] ;
    
    if ([self.arrayForCart containsObject:self.selectedDict]) {
        _oldDict = [self.arrayForCart objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.updatedDict addEntriesFromDictionary:_oldDict];
        [self.updatedDict setObject:clickedCell.qtyDisplayLbl.text forKey:@"qty"];
        [self.arrayForCart replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:self.updatedDict];
    }else {
        [self.arrayForCart addObject:self.updatedDict];
    }
            but it updates all keys of added objects

Comment: Then you looked at the wrong examples.